# ¿Cómo borrar un texto guardado en un array de un fichero txt?

Tags: java, array, archivo, filewriter

Estoy realizando un ejercicio en el que tengo que borrar un una posición de un array en un archivo txt previamente creado con bufferedWriter, pero creo que me está fallando algo y no sé que es.

Estos son los 3 métodos que estoy usando para crear, rellenar y eliminar el contenido del fichero, el que me falla es el de eliminar que no me quita el array que deseo.

```
public static void crearFitxer(String directori, String fitxer) throws IOException {
        File f1=new File(directori,fitxer);

        if (!f1.exists()) {
            f1.createNewFile();
        }
    }

    public static void insertarAlumnes(String directori,String fitxer) {
        String a1,a2,a3,a4,a5;

        System.out.println("Vamos a insertar 5 Alumnos para nuestra clase:");

        System.out.println("Nombre del alumno 1:");
        a1= lector.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Nombre del alumno 2:");
        a2= lector.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Nombre del alumno 3:");
        a3= lector.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Nombre del alumno 4:");
        a4= lector.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Nombre del alumno 5:");
        a5= lector.nextLine();

        String[] alumnes = {a1,a2,a3,a4,a5};

            BufferedWriter fichero;
            try {
                fichero = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(directori+"\\"+fitxer));
                for (String alumno : alumnes) {
                    fichero.write(alumno + "\n");
                }
                fichero.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("La operacion no se ha realizado con exito");
            }
    }

    public static void eliminarAlumne(String[] alumnes) {
        int respuesta;
        System.out.println("Que alumno deseas eliminar?");
        respuesta = lector.nextInt();

        int i = respuesta;
        for (; i < alumnes.length - 1; i++) {
            alumnes[i] = alumnes[i + 1];
        }
        alumnes[i] = " ";
    }
```

Comment: No le veo nada de malo al código. ¿Podrías decir por qué no te borra el texto? ¿Qué falla tiene?

Comment: Pues yo en el main pido la ruta y el nombre del fichero, si este existe coge el fichero, sino lo crea, entonces paso a un menu donde pregunta que deseo si voy al metodo de escribir, escribe correctamente, pero cuando le digo que deseo eliminar por ejemplo le introduzco en la respuesta ( del metodo de eliminar) el 1 para eliminar ese nombre, al ver el contenido aparece todo como si no hubiera eliminado nada.

Comment: Es porque ese código lo único que hace es "borrar" el nombre del array de String pero nunca lo hace en el fichero. Lo que puedes hacer es crear un nuevo fichero y copiar todo el contenido del fichero anterior en el nuevo pero sin incluir la línea que quieres eliminar.

Comment: Mmm ahora que dices esto habia alguna manera de sobreescribir mi fichero? Ya que se guarda en el array en la memoria volátil, mientras no cierre el programa sigue ahi, si cojo y reemplazo por los nuevos datos... Aunque nose si esto se puede ni como se haria se que cada vez que pregunto por añadir los alumnos aunque el fichero este lleno me lo sobreescribe y mete los nuevos datos

Comment: En el segundo parámetro del constructor de `FileWriter`, escribe un `true` (por ejemplo: `new FileWriter("test.txt", true)`). Esto hace que cada vez que escribas en el fichero, se añade al final, por lo tanto, cuando cierres el programa y lo vuelvas a ejecutar para escribir de nuevo en el archivo, lo hará al final del fichero, por ende, no sobrescribirá el contenido del archivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Estos son los 3 metodos que estoy usando para crear, rellenar y eliminar el contenido del fichero, el que me falla es el de eliminar que no me quita el array que deseo.

Este código:

```java
int i = respuesta;
for (; i < alumnes.length - 1; i++) 
   alumnes[i] = alumnes[i + 1];
alumnes[i] = " ";
```

Lo que elimina es el nombre del alumno que esté en el arreglo de objetos de tipo `String`, sin embargo, el nombre seguirá guardado en el archivo, debido a que, en ningún momento se creó un algoritmo para poder lograr dicho objetivo.

Para poder borrar el nombre del alumno de un fichero, lo que se necesita es tener la ruta donde está el archivo original con los datos (nombres de alumnos). Posteriormente, cambiamos el nombre del fichero original a un nombre auxiliar. Por ejemplo, si el archivo original se llamaba `nombres.txt`, lo cambiamos a `auxnombres.txt`. Después creamos un nuevo archivo con el mismo nombre del fichero original (`nombres.txt`).

Teniendo estos dos ficheros creados, debemos copiar los datos del archivo `auxnombres.txt` en `nombres.txt` sin incluir el nombre que se quiere eliminar.

Por último, eliminamos el fichero `auxnombres.txt`, debido a que, los datos originales estarán en `nombres.txt` y listo, con este algoritmo deberíamos de tener un archivo actualizado sin el nombre que se haya eliminado.

En código sería así:

```java
public static void eliminarAlumne(String directori, String fitxer) throws IOException
    {
        String path_fileOri = directori + "\\" + fitxer;
        String path_fileAux = directori + "\\" + "aux" + fitxer;
        String nomAlumno, n;
        BufferedWriter bufout = null;
        BufferedReader bufread = null;  
        File fl = new File(path_fileOri);
        if(!fl.exists())
        {
            System.out.println("No existe dicho archivo!");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Que alumno deseas eliminar?");
        nomAlumno = lector.nextLine();
        //Cambiamos el nombre del archivo original (nombres.txt a auxnombres.txt)
        fl.renameTo(new File(path_fileAux));
        //Creamos un nuevo archivo con el mismo nombre del archivo original (nombres.txt), por defecto estará vacío el archivo.
        fl.createNewFile(); 
        try
        {
            bufout = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path_fileOri));
            bufread = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path_fileAux));
            while((n = bufread.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if(!nomAlumno.equals(n))
                {
                    bufout.write(n);
                    bufout.newLine();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: "+ e.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            if(bufout != null)
                bufout.close();
            if(bufread != null)
                bufread.close();
            //Eliminamos el archivo auxiliar
            new File(path_fileAux).delete();
        }
    }
```

**Recomendación:**

No cierres los recursos adentro del bloque `try` (para más información: [Java: Buenas prácticas para el manejo de Excepciones](https://www.clubdetecnologia.net/blog/2017/java-buenas-practicas-para-el-manejo-de-excepciones/)), debido a que, si llegara a ocurrir una excepción, la memoria que se haya reservado anteriormente no se liberará y corres el riesgo que se produzca un [memory leak](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuga_de_memoria).

Por lo tanto, se recomienda cerrar los recursos en el bloque `finally`.

También puedes hacer una gestión automática de recursos a partir de Java 7 usando esta sintaxis:

```java
try(BufferedWriter bufout = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path_fileOri));
BufferedReader bufread = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path_fileAux)))
{
    //code
}
catch(IOException e)
{
   //print
}
```

De este modo no necesitas estar a cada rato liberando los recursos manualmente (con el método `close`).

Comment: Disculpa la tardanza en responderte, no he podido hacerlo antes :) es exactamente lo que necesitaba muchisimas gracias!!!!! no sabia que se podia añadir al fichero un nombre escribiendole en el string por ejemplo auxiliar.Tampoco sabia que era mejor finalizarlo en un bloque finally ya que en clase no me habian explicado esto. En Java 7 se cierran solos?

Comment: @azucarilla Si a partir de Java 7 puedes usar los [bloques ARM](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/automatic-resource-management-java/) para gestionar los recursos automáticamente. Esto quiere decir que los objetos quedan liberados de la memoria cuando el bloque `try` termine de ejecutarse.

Comment: muchísimas gracias por explicarme!!! tendré en cuanta que a partir de java 7 es diferente :)